# While updating content in Sitecore RTE programmatically it is removing line breaks

Tags: richtext-editor

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 2 in our project. Currently facing issue when adding content to the Rich Text Editor programmatically it is removing new lines and line breaks automatically and the content displays as plain text. Please refer below images.

**When adding content programmatically: *There are no breaks in the content***
[image]

**When adding content directly in the content editor: *Here we can see the line breaks***
[image]

Please help me in fixing this issue how can we insert line breaks when adding content programmatically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add code snippet that you use to add content programatically to your question

Comment: sample.Editing.BeginEdit();
    var htmlFieldValue = "1970 Abitur am Wirtschaftsgymnasium Wiesbaden. \nAusbildung";
    sample["Career"] = htmlFieldValue;
    sample.Editing.EndEdit();

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the raw value of the field when it's been edited manually and looks the way you want it?

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore.config you have a setting for LineBreak, default value is **"p"**

```
 <!--  HTML EDITOR LINE BREAK
            Specifies the tag that the HTML editor inserts on Enter. Values can be
            "br", "div" and "p".
      -->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.LineBreak" value="p" />
```

Look like you are using a different string for linebreak in your code.

Comment: I tried changing vale "p" to "br" like  <setting name="HtmlEditor.LineBreak" value="br" /> but still issue exists.

Comment: If you are changing it to `br` then you need to insert it like this "1970 Abitur am Wirtschaftsgymnasium Wiesbaden. <br \>Ausbildung"

Comment: Is this ok if i change the code like  sample["Career"] =  Regex.Replace(htmlFieldValue.TrimEnd(), @"\r\n?|\n", "<br>")